# Unread items in the achievements tab has some padding at the top

Tags: bug, status-completed, achievements-dialog, global-inbox

There is some extra padding at the top of unread achievements making it look unaligned as the below image clearly shows with red freehand circles and arrows:

[image: Image showing extra padding-top for unread achievements]

Chromium Version 74.0.3729.169, Linux

Comment: I noticed that too and [posted a bug report on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330794/295232).

Comment: Ha, I didn't search it up in Meta SE. Also, now that I got a notification from your comment, I noticed this same issue for the inbox tab as well

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce on the latest version of Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. I posted this on Glorfindel's report as well, but it was supposed to have more padding on both the top and the bottom so it doesn't look as crushed. It should be fixed now! Thanks again

Comment: Thanks, but honestly, no padding is the one that looks perfect. Right now, it looks weird with the extra padding on both sides